# Can you specify a type for function argument in erlang using apply(M, F, A)?

Tags: erlang

In the example below, I would like to specify a type for argument in the `apply(M, F, A)` call, but I can't figure how. Here, `dialyzer` doesn't complain for type mismatch between `{event, "something append !"}` and `{anyevent, string()}` type definition in `callback_function` spec :

```
-module(erl_test).

-export([
         callback_function/1,
         test_it/0
        ]).

-spec callback_function(
  Event::{anyevent, string()}) -> ok.
callback_function(Event) ->
  io:format("event received: ~p~n", [Event]),
  ok.

-spec notify_something(CbMod::module(), CbFun::atom()) -> ok.
notify_something(CbMod, CbFun) ->
  apply(CbMod, CbFun, [{event, "something append !"}]),
  ok.

test_it() ->
  notify_something(?MODULE, callback_function).
```

Or do you have any other design proposition that I could use to do type checking on a callback function ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `apply/3` as it is, I believe you are out of luck.
However, you could change the line:

```
apply(CbMod, CbFun, [{event, "something append !"}]),
```

to:

```
CbMod:CbFun([{event, "something append !"}]),
```

This would make Dialyzer aware of the specified argument type.

Comment: thank you ! works perfectly with `CbMod:CbFun({event, "something append !"}),`